# DOORS DXL Recreating the Main Column

Tags: ibm-doors

I would like to create an DXL attribute in DOORS that contains the same information as the main column.
It is important to maintain the same heading font style in the attribute as in the main column as this is used for automatic creation of "Table of content" in the Word document after DOORS Publish.

I found the below dxl-script on the internet, but getCanvas does not seem to work.
All text are passed fine to my new attribute, but the heading have the same font style as normal text.

if (obj."Object Heading" "" != "")
{
font(getCanvas, level(obj), HeadingsFont)
displayRich(number(obj) " " obj."Object Heading" "")
}

if (obj."Object Text" "" != "")
{
font(getCanvas, level(obj), TextFont)
displayRich(richTextWithOle(obj."Object Text"))
}

Can anyone help?

KR
Klaus

Answer (score 0):

For me, the code actually does work in a Layout-DXL column (which is not a DXL attribute).

```
if (obj."Object Heading" "" != "") {
    DBE dbCanvas = getCanvas()
    font(dbCanvas, level(obj), HeadingsFont)
    displayRich(number(obj) " " obj."Object Heading" "")
}
```

My DOORS version is 9.6, although the methods don't seem to be that new, so DOORS version does not seem to be the issue.

If nothing else helps regarding the DXL code, I would suggest that you have a look at your target word document. There, you should be able to control anything you paste into the document via VBA code in a post-processing step. Although I didn't really get, why you are avoiding using the main column for your source content. Are you trying to show content of a linked or referenced module?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answer. It helped me somehow.

My problem was that I was trying to enter the dxl-code in an attribute. I followed your suggestion and made an Layout-DXL Column instead and it worked almost immediately :-)
I ended up with the dxl-code as shown below.

```
if (obj."Object Heading" "" != "")
{
    DBE dbCanvas = getCanvas()
    if( dbCanvas != null )
        font(dbCanvas, level(obj), HeadingsFont)
    displayRich(number(obj) " " obj."Object Heading" "")
}
else
{   // insert rest of text
    if ( probeAttr_(obj, "Requirement") == "Requirement" ) 
    {   // insert requirement text from DT module
        displayRich(richText(obj."DXL to DT - ID & Object Text"))
    }
    else
    {   // insert rest of text from this module
        displayRich(richTextWithOle(obj."Object Text"))
    }
}
```

I would like to have a publish of the Test Procedure where every Test Case starts with the requirement text followed by the test steps necessary to perform the test as shown in Fig 1.
[Test Procedure Publish view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w1uy.png)

The view in DOORS now looks like I want, but I get error when publishing in DOORS.

[DOORS publish error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqB7w.png)

I therefore protected the line "font(dbCanvas, level(obj), HeadingsFont)", but now I get no headings in the Word document and Table of Content is empty.

[Word snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJk5U.png)

Is there a solution to this?

KR
Klaus

Comment: Please define "when publishing". What do you call / what code do you use to "publish"?